# Horizontal center img troublshoot

Tags: html, css

When I take this apart in jsfiddle I can center an image no problem but something is messing it up on my website. I'm a dummy and this is my personal site so I don't stand to profit from your help.

Here is a working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/5hoLq4q3/

Here is the not working website.
http://rollinleonard.com/indexxy.php

Here's the perfectly functional css

```
    a img, img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! now I gotta figure out why adding that float messes it up. it doesn't make sense to me but at least that problem is solved.

Comment: `float:left` shifts the image to the left edge of the container. Doing exactly what it states. if it's something else that's not clear let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your website, you have an `img` selector with a `float: left` declaration.

```
img { float: left; }
```

This float is not applied in  your fiddle.

Remove this rule and the image centers on your website. In testing, removing this rule had no impact on other elements.